# How to split Fromdate and Todate based on weekdays(Sat,Sun) using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, weekday

I have Fromdate and Todate.I need to split Fromdate&Todate based on weekdays(Sat,Sun) to list

```
Fromdate-11/03/2016
Todate-31/03/2016
```

Model:

```
public class Splitdate
{
    public DateTime Fromdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Todate { get; set; }
}
```

I need Output in one list:

```
list[0]=Fromdate:11/03/2016 Todate:11/03/2016
list[1]=Fromdate:14/03/2016 Todate:18/03/2016
list[2]=Fromdate:21/03/2016 Todate:25/03/2016
list[3]=Fromdate:28/03/2016 Todate:31/03/2016
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: based on weekdays(Sat,Sun) ? What do you mean ?

Comment: please explain more.

Comment: i need to filter  from date and todate based on week days.For example If i choose Sat,Sun,It splits dates to list

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DateTime tempStart = StartDate;
var list = new List<Splitdate>();
for (DateTime date = StartDate; date.Date <= EndDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        var temp = new Splitdate();
        temp.Fromdate = tempStart;
        temp.Todate = date.AddDays(-1);
        list.Add(temp);
        tempStart.AddDays(2);
    }
}
if (tempStart <= EndDate)
{
    var temp = new Splitdate();
    temp.Fromdate = tempStart;
    temp.Todate = EndDate;
    list.Add(temp);
}
```

DateTime has a built in DayOfWeek property. Loop through the days from the Fromdate to the Todate and add to a list based on the DayOfWeek value.

Comment: @Mari Fixed. It was a copy paste error from some old code of mine.